# how to refresh values of labels from listbox c#

Tags: c#, label, refresh

Hello guys im lookin for any help about my code i need to solve about refreshing values in my labels from listbox. I work on players with his statistics,matches etc.. and i wanna see his specific scores for the match(which i can choose from listbox) and see his kills/deaths in while im swaping matches, anyone has idea? Thanks for attention. Sorry for my english. Lanky is Lans,Jménohráče is First name, Věk is Age, Země is Country. Počet killu means Count of kills, and the other means count of deaths, Veškeré odehrané lanky means all his played matches.

```
private void listBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        var q = "SELECT * FROM Lanky";
        var query = new SqlCommand(q, connection);
        using (var dr = query.ExecuteReader())
        {
            var success = dr.Read();
            if (success)
            {
                label8.Text = dr["Kills"].ToString();
                label9.Text = dr["Deaths"].ToString();
                label1.Text = dr["Jménohráče"].ToString();
                label2.Text = dr["Věk"].ToString();
                label3.Text = dr["Země"].ToString();

            }
        }
        connection.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("error " + ex);
    }

}
```

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/BiEHo.png]

Comment: Hi, In the list box there is an option to handle on change event, So implement that function and in that function you can get selected value based on this you have to update your labels

Comment: Your query should be something like `"SELECT * FROM Lanky WHERE MatchId = " + id;` with the `id` derived from `listBox1.SelectedItem`.

Comment: Ye but anyone knows how to changs values in labels ? because i can see 12 kills and 10 deaths but when i have clicked on NHL so labels dont change still 12/10... but in my database has in NHL match 20 kils and 12 deaths.

Comment: You could change Listbox **AutoPostBack** property to **True**. If you don't want page postback then use the scriptmanager.

Answer (score 0):

there should be method which fills listbox and another one that fires on listbox select. You have put data retrievel in listbox changed event. Do something like this:

first, move code from listbox1_SelectedItemChanged into Form_Load event, like this:

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
            try
            {
                connection.Open();
                var q = "SELECT * FROM Lanky";
                var query = new SqlCommand(q, connection);
                using (var dr = query.ExecuteReader())
                {

                    ListBox1.Items.Clear();
                    while (dr.Read())
                    {
                        ListBox1.Items.Add(dr["Jménohráče"]);
                    }
                }

                connection.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("error " + ex);
            }

        }
```

Next, in selectedItem changed do somethign like this:

```
private void ListBox1_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
    try
    {
        connection.Open();
        var q = "SELECT * FROM Lanky WHERE Jménohráče  = @jh";
        var query = new SqlCommand(q, connection);
        query.Parameters.Add("@jh", ListBox1.SelectedValue.ToString())
        using (var dr = query.ExecuteReader())
        {

            ListBox1.Items.Clear();
            dr.Read();

            label8.Text = dr["Kills"].ToString();
            label9.Text = dr["Deaths"].ToString();
            label1.Text = dr["Jménohráče"].ToString();
            label2.Text = dr["Věk"].ToString();
            label3.Text = dr["Země"].ToString();

        }

        connection.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("error " + ex);
    }

}
```